# In wordpress version 4.8.2 javacsript file is not including. Below is a code of functions.php

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress version 4.8.2 JavacScript file is not including. Below is a code of functions.php:

```
function niksBlog_resource()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_register_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', null, 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script ('main_js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','niksBlog_resource');
```

Comment: For more specific answers for WordPress related questions ask here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: If that script has no dependencies, use an empty array instead of null. Is it not added to the output or is its' code just not being executed (because it produces a 404 for example)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the official way to add custom js files in WordPress.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts', 12);
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('filename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/filename.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

In your case do this.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','niksBlog_resource', 12);
function niksBlog_resource() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), 1.0, true);
}
```

I passed the data to `wp_enqueue_script` function, and also pass an empty array if no dependencies.

reference [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

reference [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)